# forEach is not a function and for...of is not iterable

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, foreach, for-of-loop

In my TS class I have a method that supposed to iterate through an array of objects, which is received as an argument. For some reason, when I tried to iterate it with `forEach`, I'm suddenly getting a `forEach is not a function` error message.

```
places.forEach(place => {
  this.addMarker(place.id(), place.coords(), ...);
});
```

So I tried to use the `for...of`iterator:

```
for (const place of places) {
  this.addMarker(place.id(), place.coords(), ...);
};
```

And I got the `places is not iterable` error message.

So I tried the good old `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
  this.addMarker(places[i].id(), places[i].coords(), ...);
};
```

And it worked just fine.

Though it works, it just doesn't look very nice with all these `places[i]` and I'm not sure it's a good idea to use `for` loop in TS file, with all the modern iterators available.

So the question is: why didn't forEach and for...of work? Is it possible to make them work? Perhaps there are other alternatives or I shouldn't even be bothered with that?

**EDIT**

Explanation to what `places` is:

Filter class:

```
export class FilterUtility {
  private placesList = ko.observableArray([]);
  private placesFilter = ko.observable('');
  private storage = new StorageManager();

  setFilter = (category?: any) => {
    if (category == null) {
      this.placesFilter('');
    } else if(category == 'favorites') {
      this.placesFilter(category)
    }
    else {
      this.placesFilter(category.id());
    }
  };

  filteredPlaces = ko.computed(() => {
    let self = this;
    if(!self.placesFilter() || self.placesFilter() == null || self.placesFilter() == '') {
      return this.placesList();
    } else if(self.placesFilter() == 'favorites') {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.placesList(), function(place: Place){
        return self.storage.isPlaceInFavorites(place.id());
      });
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.placesList(), function(place: Place){
        return place.categoryId() == self.placesFilter();
      });
    }
  });

  getFilteredPlaces = () => {
    return this.filteredPlaces;
  };

  addPlace = (place) => {
    this.placesList.push(place);
  }
```

Main.ts:

```
$.when(db.getPlacesDataFromMongoLab()).done(placesData => {
    placesData[0].forEach(place => {
        filter.addPlace(new Place(place));
    })
});

this.manageMap = (data) => {
  if (isFirstRun && data == "favorites"){
    isFirstRun = false;
  } else {
    filter.setFilter(data);
    map.renderMarkers(filter.getFilteredPlaces(), self.categoriesList) 
  }
};
```

The manageMap method is binded to click on links with Knockout.

Map class:

```
renderMarkers = function(places, categories) {...}
```

Comment: Probably `places` isn't an array but is some other object with a length property. You haven't shown us how it is defined. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Andy — `places[i]` has that property, not `places`

Comment: Please show us what `places` is. Your for loop will work on objects, so `places` is probably an object.

Comment: @Quentin Edited the question. Hope now it's more clear what places is. One thing I thought of: `$.when(filter.getFilteredPlaces()).done(result => {
          map.renderMarkers(result(), self.categoriesList);
        });` Then the forEach and for...of loops worked just fine

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Please see my answer to Quentin above. Thanks!

Comment: The update still doesn't tell us what `places` is. Where and how is it set?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Updated again. Hopefully now it's more clear. Basically I'm getting the places data from MongoLab db, then iterate it, create a Place object from each place I get from DB and push it to Knockout observableArray. Then, when asked, Filter return either the full observableArray or filtered by category, depending on what link the user clicked.

Comment: Take a look at this wonderful article: [the iterator interface](https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_z2tOOXM8qO), it might help you.

Answer (score -2):

Try it this way:

```
if ( typeof places !== "undefined" && places!== null) { 
{
    places.forEach(function(place) {
        console.log(place); //<- Or whatever            
    });
}
```

Comment: It's definitely not undefined nor null - it's being logged out and it's an array...